# Compilation failure on Axis plugin with java 7

Tags: java, maven, axis

I am not really familiar with SOAP, so it is really an enigma for me. Also - not very popular in the Net. I suppose that is because of the Java version.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile
>   (default-compile) on project XXX: Compilation failure: Compilation
>   failure: [ERROR] ootstrap class path not set in conjunction with
>   -source 1.7

Comment: This looks like there's a problem with your maven setup for building with java 7.  Make sure you've got a *jdk* for version 7, not just the jre

Comment: The setup works with other WSDL.

Comment: look for a `<source>` tag in the other maven pom.  Betting its something other than 1.7